# How to initiate process for a script via cronjob, monitor status, and log execution time

Tags: shell-script, process, cron, monitoring, logs

How to initiate process for a script that will run via cronjob, then monitor the status, and log start and stop run time. Any code snippet will be helpful... Thanks

Comment: Hi Riz, what have you tried so far ?